# ld.gold: internal error in set_info_section, at output.h:3209

Tags: gold-linker

when i was migrating ld to gold, I met the following errors:

ld.gold: internal error in set_info_section, at output.h:3209

my gold is binutil-2.25-gold.

I didn't get any clues from google. anyone know this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you come up with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces this issue? It smells of "bug in gold" to me...

Comment: looks g++5.2.0 crashed but 4.5.2 passed.  and the issue exist in binutil-2.29.    reproduce command: g++ 
-o 
libnew.o 
-fuse-ld=gold 
-B/u/heng/gold/binutils-2.29/binutils-2.29-gold/bin 
-m64 
-msse2 
-pthread 
-static-libstdc++ 
-static-libgcc 
-Wl,-r 
-nostdlib 
-g 
-Wl,--whole-archive 
libstdc++_fPIC.a 
lto-g.o

Comment: Where does this lto-g.o file come from?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a linker script? If so, please attach it.

Your version of gold is pretty old. If you can, please try your build with binutils-2.29 or later. There's a good chance the bug has been fixed.

If you are using a script, I'm going to take a wild guess and suggest that you look for a .rela.dyn : { ... } block in the script and simply remove it. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: 1. No there is not a linker script;

2. same issue for binutils-2.29 or binutils-2.29-1;

any other clues?

Comment: I'll need to see your reproducer in order to track this down. I see you've posted a command line, but not the object files required to run it. Please file a [bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/).